# Counter is not updated and it's value is replaced by the current value

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, forms

I'm using 4 drop-down lists in an html form. The 2 drop downs, represent the starting and ending month of an activity and the other 2 represent the starting and the ending year of an activity. I'm allowing the user to enter a 3 year history and after completion, I prompt the user to go to the next section. To calculate the 3 year history, I take the difference between the start and ending month and I enter it each time in a counter (note that I am working with numbers and not with the Date object). The values are passed into my arrays, but the counter is not updated. It is just replaced by the new value in the array. Can anyone tell me where is the problem? Here is my code:

```
var arrMonthStarted = [];  //It stores the month that activity started
var arrMonthEnded = [];   //It stores the month that activity ended
var arrYearStarted = []; //It stores the year that activity started
var arrYearEnded = [];  //It stores the year that activity ended
function validatedropdowns1(){
var monthStarted = document.getElementById('idMonthStarted').value;   
var yearStarted = document.getElementById('idYearStarted').value;    
var monthEnded = document.getElementById('idMonthEnded').value;     
var yearEnded = document.getElementById('idYearEnded').value;     
arrMonthStarted.push(monthStarted);  
arrMonthEnded.push(monthEnded);     
arrYearStarted.push(yearStarted);    
arrYearEnded.push(yearEnded);
//Calculating the 3-year history
var count = 0;
if(yearStarted == yearEnded){
    if(monthEnded < monthStarted){
        var temp = monthEnded;
        monthEnded = monthStarted;
        monthStarted = temp;
    }
    var diffmonths = monthEnded - monthStarted;
    count = count + diffmonths;
}
//Take the difference between the years.
var subYears = yearEnded - yearStarted;
//If 1, just take the difference on the first 2 lines of the calendar 
if(subYears == 1){
    var subLine1 = 12 - monthStarted;
    var subLine2 = 12 - monthEnded;
    var finalLine2 = 12 - subLine2;
    var takeresult = subLine1 + finalLine2;
    count = count + takeresult;
}
//Follow case 1, but also add 12 months
if(subYears == 2){
    var subLine3 = 12 - monthStarted;
    var subLine4 = 12 - monthEnded;
    var finalLine3 = 12 - subLine4;
    var takeresult11 = subLine3 + finalLine4;
    var takeresult1 = 12 + takeresult11;
    count = count + takeresult1l; 
}
//add another 12 months (24 now) on step 1.
if(subYears == 3){
    var subLine5 = 12 - monthStarted;
    var subLine6 = 12 - monthEnded;
    var finalLine5 = 12 - subLine6;
    var takeresult22 = subLine5 + finalLine6;
    var takeresult2 = 24 + takeresult22;
    count = count + takeresult2; 
}
var arrCount = []; // array to hold the count var
arrCount.push(count); // push count into arrCount 

//print total months
for(var m = 0; m < arrCount.length; m++){
    alert("The array now has" + "" + "" + count + "" + "months");
}

if(arrCount == 36){
    alert("You have successfuly finished this section. Please go to the next section. Thank you.")
    document.getElementById('btnAdd').disable = true;
}

if(arrMonthEnded[arrMonthEnded.length - 1] - arrMonthStarted[arrMonthSarted.length] > 1){
    alert("There should not be a gap of more than a month in your 3 year activity. Fill in all the months and select from the list what you were doing each month. Thank you.")
}
}
```

Also, I was trying to test the gap between the end date and the next start date. For example if I enter 12 2011 as an end date and 03 2012 as the next start date, I would like to see if there is a gap of more than one month. I tried the code below, but it didn't work

```
if(arrMonthEnded[arrMonthEnded.length - 1] - arrMonthStarted[arrMonthSarted.length] > 1){
    alert("There should not be a gap of more than a month in your 3 year activity. Fill in all the months and select from the list what you were doing each month. Thank you.")
}
```

Thank you in advance (KSFIDDLE http://jsfiddle.net/k4dNb/)

Comment: Can you post this as a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Sure... Here it is http://jsfiddle.net/k4dNb/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This loop is pointless, as the array will only ever have one item:

```
for(var m = 0; m < arrCount.length; m++){
```

Here you are comparing an array to a number, and eventhough that actually works because both will be converted to strings, and the string value of `[36]` is `"36"` which is the same as the string value of `36` which is `"36"`, it's done in a confusing way:

```
if(arrCount == 36){
```

Typo, you wrote `arrMonthSarted` instead of `arrMonthStarted`:

```
if(arrMonthEnded[arrMonthEnded.length - 1] - arrMonthStarted[arrMonthSarted.length] > 1){
```

Also, `arrMonthStarted[arrMonthStarted.length]` will always return `undefined`, as you are trying to access an item beyond the last item of the array.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Guffa. I know that it's confusing, as working dates with pure numbers is even more insane. So what do you suggest for the gap between the months?

Comment: @AndreUk13: Subtract one from the indexes that you have, but first check if `arrMonthEnded` contains at least two items so that there is a previous end date. Besides, you would need to incorporate the years into the values too, to handle months in different years.

Comment: Yeah sure. Because if someone puts 01 2012 and 01 2013 it will not evaluate as it is now. So more or less: if(arrMonthEnded >= 2) { if(arrMonthEnded[arrMonthEnded.length - 1] - arrMonthStarted[arrMonthSarted.length -1] > 1){ //code here } }). Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Yes, but with three edits: `if(arrMonthEnded.length >= 2) { if(arrMonthEnded[arrMonthEnded.length - 2] - arrMonthStarted[arrMonthStarted.length -1] > 1){ //code here } }`

Comment: I would like to make a correction on the above, just in case you need something similar in the future. `arrMonthEnded[arrMonthEnded.length - 2]` will look 2 positions upwards in the array. The first time, we have only one and putting -2, will return undefined the first time we try to compare the gap. We should put `arrMonthEnded[arrMonthEnded.length - 1]` and `arrMonthStarted[arrMonthStarted.length - 2]`, as the arrMonthStarted will always have one more element than the month ended. It's a bit confusing, but I had to draw it on a paper to get the point. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: @AndreUk13: No, you should compare the previous end date to the last start date. Now you are comparing the last end date to the previous start date, which gives you the sum of the length of the previous activity, the gap, and the length of the last activity. The `arrMonthStarted` will not have more items, as you push items to all arrays at the same time they will always be the same length. The previous date is two positions upwards, that is why you need the `if(arrMonthEnded.length >= 2)` check to skip the comparison when there is only one activity in the arrays.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37945/discussion-between-andreuk13-and-guffa)